# Vertical space before section title in moderncv

Tags: spacing, sectioning, moderncv

I'm using `moderncv` to typeset my CV. One of the challenges I have with this package is the inconsistent top margins (as shown in the MWE below). If a new page starts with a section, it will have an additional 1 cm of vertical space. A quick-and-dirty solution to this is to add `\vspace*{-1cm}` whenever this happens, but obviously this is not the best solution. I want `\section` to not add any extra space when it happens the first thing in a page. How can I do this?

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{purple}  % No, I don't really use purple for my CV
\firstname{Firsty}
\familyname{Lastie}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\section{Employment}
\newpage
    \cventry{Jan.~2012 to Present}{Dream job}{World-class employer}{A megacity}{}{}

\newpage
\section{Education}
    \cventry{Sept.~2007 to Aug.~2011}{Ph.D. in \TeX ology}{University of \TeX land}{\TeX land}{}{}

\newpage
\vspace*{-1cm}       % not-so-good solution
\section{Awards and Honors}
\subsection{Awards}
    \cventry{2011}{Best Person Award}{Consortium of Bad People}{}{}{}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to replace `\vspace*` with `\vspace` in `moderncv`s definition of `\section`. Add the following to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\section}{\vspace*{2.5ex}}{\vspace{2.5ex}}{}{}
```

Comment: I recently come across `\patchcmd` quite often. I guess it's time I take a look at `etoolbox`'s manual... well, I just did.

Comment: Actually `moderncv` loads `etoolbox` too.