# Moderncv: Extra vertical space after cvitem

Tags: spacing, sectioning, moderncv

Extra vertical space is produced after `\cvitem` and before the next `\section`. Is there a better way to fix this than to use `\vspace*{-6mm}`? The problem is shown below, between the "Skills" and "Language" sections.

[image: MWE]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic} % banking, casual, classic, empty, oldstyle options  
\moderncvcolor{blue}   % black, blue, green, grey, orange, purple, red options  
\usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry} % default scale=0.7. height= scale * layoutheight

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{R\'esum\'e}     % optional

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Professional Experience}
    \cventry{Year--Year}{Intern}{Company}{Nowhere}{State}{
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Did something important here.
        \end{itemize}}

% problem with vertical space-------------------------------------------------
\section{Education}
    \cventry{06/11}{Bachelor of Arts \LaTeX}{University of \LaTeX}{}{\textit{4.0/4.0}}{}
%\vspace*{-6mm} %this will fix vertical spacing for \moderncvstyle{classic}, but create vertical spacing issues for other \moderncvstyle{xyz}.

% problem with vertical space -------------------------------------------------
\section{Skills}
    \cvitem[-1.2em]{}{
        \begin{itemize}
            \item \LaTeX
        \end{itemize}}
%\vspace*{-6mm} %this will fix vertical spacing for \moderncvstyle{classic}, but create vertical spacing issues for other \moderncvstyle{xyz}.

\section{Languages}
    \cvitem{}{
        \begin{itemize}
            \item TeX-speak
        \end{itemize}}
% \cvitem{}{job description text here}

\end{document}
```

My problem is similar to this:
[Vertical space before section title in moderncv](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58733/vertical-space-before-section-title-in-moderncv)
I couldn't successfully implement the solution found there though.

And similar to this:
[How can I remove extra space after `itemize` in moderncv?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151329/how-can-i-remove-extra-space-after-itemize-in-moderncv)
But the answer didn't work for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the following lines in the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{moderncvstyleclassic}{%
\let\oldsection\section%
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\leavevmode\unskip\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\oldsection{#1}}%
}{%
}
\makeatother
```

The redefinition of `\section` is applied only when you choose the style `classic` so if you want to change style, you have no problems.

To have better spacing, now choose `-0.5em` instead of `-1.2em` when the `\cventry` contains lists.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic} % banking, casual, classic, empty, oldstyle options
\moderncvcolor{blue}   % black, blue, green, grey, orange, purple, red options
\usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry} % default scale=0.7. height= scale * layoutheight

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{R\'esum\'e}     % optional

\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{moderncvstyleclassic}{%
\let\oldsection\section%
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\leavevmode\unskip\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\oldsection{#1}}%
}{%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Professional Experience}
    \cventry{Year--Year}{Intern}{Company}{Nowhere}{State}{
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Did something important here.
        \end{itemize}}

% problem with vertical space-------------------------------------------------
\section{Education}
    \cventry{06/11}{Bachelor of Arts \LaTeX}{University of \LaTeX}{}{\textit{4.0/4.0}}{}
%\vspace*{-6mm} %this will fix vertical spacing for \moderncvstyle{classic}, but create vertical spacing issues for other \moderncvstyle{xyz}.

% problem with vertical space -------------------------------------------------
\section{Skills}
    \cvitem[-0.5em]{}{
        \begin{itemize}
            \item \LaTeX
        \end{itemize}}
%\vspace*{-6mm} %this will fix vertical spacing for \moderncvstyle{classic}, but create vertical spacing issues for other \moderncvstyle{xyz}.

\section{Languages}
    \cvitem[-0.5em]{}{
        \begin{itemize}
            \item TeX-speak
        \end{itemize}}
% \cvitem{}{job description text here}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]