# How to set the width of dates in moderncv?

Tags: moderncv, cv

How can you custom the with of this col/field to adapt "Jun-Sep,2011" in just one line.

[image]

The MWE is copied from [Moderncv: Extra vertical space after cvitem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159810/moderncv-extra-vertical-space-after-cvitem)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic} % banking, casual, classic, empty, oldstyle options
\moderncvcolor{blue}   % black, blue, green, grey, orange, purple, red options
\usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry} % default scale=0.7. height= scale * layoutheight

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{R\'esum\'e}     % optional

\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{moderncvstyleclassic}{%
\let\oldsection\section%
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\leavevmode\unskip\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\oldsection{#1}}%
}{%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Professional Experience}
    \cventry{Start--End, Year}{Intern}{Company}{Nowhere}{State}{
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Did something important here.
    \end{itemize}}

% problem with vertical space-------------------------------------------------
\section{Education}
    \cventry{Jun-Sep, 2011}{Bachelor of Arts \LaTeX}{University of \LaTeX}{}{\textit{4.0/4.0}}{}
%\vspace*{-6mm} %this will fix vertical spacing for \moderncvstyle{classic}, but create vertical spacing issues for other \moderncvstyle{xyz}.

% problem with vertical space -------------------------------------------------
\section{Skills}
    \cvitem[-0.5em]{}{
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \LaTeX
    \end{itemize}}
%\vspace*{-6mm} %this will fix vertical spacing for \moderncvstyle{classic}, but create vertical spacing issues for other \moderncvstyle{xyz}.

\section{Languages}
    \cvitem[-0.5em]{}{
    \begin{itemize}
        \item TeX-speak
    \end{itemize}}
% \cvitem{}{job description text here}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you should use `--` instead of `-` between Jun and Sep.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The length you need to adjust is called `\hintscolumnwidth`. The default is

```
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.175\textwidth}
```

Example Output for `0.3\textwidth`:

[image: moderncv]

---

**EDIT:** You can also adjust the width automatically to the width of Jun-Sep, 2011 with:

```
\settowidth{\hintscolumnwidth}{Jun-Sep, 2011}
```